# MySQL search key in haystack

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with MySQL queries.

I have a database of books, in which there is a field called "authors"; this fields contains the IDs of the authors of the book. Eg. 16,42,100.

In the author single page, I would like to have all books of the author.

So...what is the correct query?

```
SELECT * FROM xxxx WHERE authors ???? '$author'
```

I tried with LIKE '$author%', but this solution has a bug: infact, if $author=116, the query returns me also the book with author=1116.

Thanks in advance!

Mauro

Comment: Never store multiple values in one column. Redesign your database, read about normalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need find_in_set:

```
SELECT * FROM xxxx WHERE find_in_set(author_id, authors) > 0
```

You really should normalize that database.

Answer (score 1):

You need like:

```
SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `author_id` = '2'; -- Single author.

-- Multiple authors.
SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `author_id` IN (
  SELECT `author_id` FROM (whatever)
)
```

Comment: Quote: "I tried with LIKE '$author%', but this solution has a bug: infact, if $author=116, the query returns me also the book with author=1116."

Comment: Yes, @CFreitas It is always better to keep a separate table for author-book relationship.